# SharePoint Online Result Source is missing some items from search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

We have created a Result Source in a SharePoint Online site. In Query Transform setting, we are trying with two different settings as shown below.

```
1. {searchTerms} listid:XXXXXXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-AAAA-BBBBBBBBBBBB and TicketType:Maintenance

2. {searchTerms} listid:XXXXXXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-AAAA-BBBBBBBBBBBB
```

"TicketType" is a managed property and it is searchable. This is mapped to a lookup column on the source list.

There are two items in source list that have same lookup value in "TicketType", and created in around 5 minutes gap. Both items have identical data.

We are using "Build Your Query -> TEST" option available in Result Source settings.

1. We have tried with a search keyword that matches with item 1. It is returning the results as expected for both {searchTerms} setting above.
2. Next, we have tried with a different search keyword that matches with item 2. It is returning results only with second {searchTerms} setting

It is not clear why the first setting is not returning the expected results. Any limitations/restrictions with including managed property in search Term setting? Otherwise, how to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, when you use the following search query, item 2 will not be searched：

{searchTerms} listid:XXXXXXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-AAAA-BBBBBBBBBBBB and TicketType:Maintenance

Please make sure the item 2 has the correct value:Maintenance.

If the value is true, please search without the managed property to check if the item 2 could be searched.

Comment: Thanks for your response. both items have same value in the lookup column (TicketType) i.e. "Maintenance Request". If I search without the managed property in {searchTerms} setting then item 2 is coming into the result as expected so it is unclear why item 2 is not coming in to search results with managed property.

Comment: I could reproduce your issue per my test, it seems related to duplicate items aren't listed in SharePoint Online search, please refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/search/near-duplicate-items-are-not-listed-in-search-results#:~:text=To%20show%20the%20View%20Duplicates,box%2C%20and%20then%20click%20OK.

Comment: I will click the "show the View Duplicates link" on classic search center and SharePoint server , and then give you feedback as soon as possible.